# Getting a surface graph from a json file in gnuplot

Tags: json, gnuplot

I'm not a dev, I'm doing this for a school project. I'm trying to put the following dataset into a surface plot in windows gnuplot. qt type terminal, if that's important.

https://files.catbox.moe/nbc6l1.json

As you can see, it's a huge set of data. Pulled directly from an image and into a csv file, which I converted to json.

[When I type in "splot 'C:\Users\tyler\ESRP Data\sampleOutput.json'", this is what I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJgYb.jpg)

As you can see, there's only a single line, when there should be something approaching an intensity chart in a 3 dimensional space. Is it a problem with the data? Do I need a specific command to do this?

Comment: You would probably do better to plot the original image file, or the derived csv file.  Gnuplot does not know anything about json.

Comment: The .csv worked even less. How would I plot the original image?

Comment: Minimal answer: `plot "filename.png" binary filetype=png with rgbimage`.  If that isn't the answer you need then please provide more information about what kind of file you have, what kind of plot you want, and what commands you have tried.

Comment: It looks like it is graphing, but it's just pasting the image onto a graph. It isn't creating a surface graph, even when I use splot. The raw image file is a png, showing a scan of the distortions in a surface, and I'm trying to graph the magnitude of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help if you attached an example of your image data to the question, and also if you provided a link to a plot similar to the one you are trying to create. There are many different styles one might use to represent a surface. I will attempt to guess at a possible solution.

Input image (scribbled in GIMP and saved as a png image):

[image: Scribbled in GIMP and saved as a png file]

Gnuplot surface plot:

```
set border -1
unset tics

# surface represented by colored lines in 3D
# down-sample by 4x in each dimension to get an interpretable surface
set palette defined (0 "blue", 1 "white")
splot 'scribble.png' binary filetype=png every 4:4:4 using 1:2:3:3 with lines lc palette
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect for what I need. Now I just need to figure out how to do it with this image.

Comment: Update, it's worked perfectly. Thank you so much for taking the time to do this. I know how to modify it for the look I need from here.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Please mark the question as answered ("accepted") so that others with a similar question can find it in the future.  That's the way this site works.